# Haskell error: parse error on input '='

Tags: haskell

I created a new quick.hs file in the ghci.exe directory. And the content is

```
quicksort::(Ord a)=>[a]->[a]  
quicksort []=[]  
quicksort (x:xs)=  
    let smaller = [a |a<-xs,a<=x]  
        larger = [a |a<-xs,a>x]  
    in  quicksort smaller ++ [x] ++ quicksort larger
```

When I issue ***:l quick*** in the ghci command lline, the output is

```
Prelude> :l quick
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( quick.hs, interpreted )

quick.hs:5:17: error:
    parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I have concured this kind of problems many times. What's wrong on earth?

Comment: [No repro](http://ideone.com/Zdflsx) Are you sure there are no tab characters in the file?

Comment: Looks OK to me. Use `-Wall` and check if it reports tabs in your code instead of spaces. (quick.sh instead of quick.hs above is just a typo in the posted question, right?)

Comment: I rewrited the code and made sure there is no tab in the file. But the error is still there......

Comment: Is `larger` exactly defined on the same column as `smaller`?

Comment: yes, I'm sure about it

Comment: which version of GHC ?

Comment: version 8.0.1 , on Windows 7

Comment: @chi, was `-fwarn-tabs` included in `-Wall` before it was enabled by default?

Comment: @dfeuer Good point -- I somehow assumed it was...

Answer (score 8):

You say in the comments that you are sure there are no tab characters in the source file, but inspecting the source of your question, indeed there is one right before the `in` token. Replace that with the appropriate number of spaces and you'll be all good.

Comment: I swear I have replaced all the tab characters with the appropriate number of spaces , but the error is still there

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove all tabs and change it by spaces. I hope that this instruction helps you.